# PyCharm doesn't understand custom Manager of model

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, pycharm, django-managers

I extend default model manager and add cache-specific logic to it:

```
class ReadOnlyManager(manager.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        obj = super(ReadOnlyManager, self).create(**kwargs)
        cache.cache_read_only_object(obj)
        ...
        return obj

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise ReadOnlyException()

    def by_id(self, object_id):
        return cache.retrieve_read_only_object(self.model, object_id)

    def by_lookup(self, lookup_key, lookup_value):
        return cache.retrieve_read_only_object_by_lookup(self.model, lookup_key, lookup_value)
```

Then I created abstract model that uses it:

```
class ReadOnlyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    objects = ReadOnlyManager()
```

I use it in concrete model:

```
class TokenType(ReadOnlyModel):
    code = models.CharField(_('code'), max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(_('description'), max_length=100)

    lookups = {
        'code': 'code'
    }
```

When I tried to call method specific for custom cache, for example *by_id*:

```
TokenType.objects.by_id(1) # This code works
```

PyCharm highlights it and writes "Unresolved attribute reference" warning. When I press CMD+Space after `TokenType.`, I see, that autocomplete box contains two *objects* items: one marked with function icon and have type ReadOnlyManager, second - with method icon and have type Manager.

Is it PyCharm bug? How to enable autocomlete for additional methods in custom manager?

Comment: seperate from your problem, I recommend you use the IssueTracker on jetbrains, they really pick up these things fast

Comment: @ArgsKwargs, thanks, posted it. Will update this topic when get answer.

Comment: @Marboni, any response from JetBrains? Just found this issue annoying :)

Comment: @Munhitsu, PyCharm support answered that they plan to fix it in 1.6: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6664. In ticket I see "Fixed in build -> 120.113".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem of `PyCharm`. Writing an auto completion for Python is really a hard task, especially for things like `Django Models`, which uses `Meta Classes` and other nasty stuff.

However it is possible to complete, and it seems not so difficult, for your example my autocompletion ( https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/tree/dev, work in progress, don't use it yet) is able to complete it:

Completing `TokenType.objects.` :

```
update                
by_id                 
by_lookup             
create                
use_for_related_fields
```

Completing `TokenType.`:

```
__metaclass__                 
__hash__                      
_get_next_or_previous_in_order
__ne__                        
date_error_message            
description                   
_perform_date_checks          
delete                        
clean                         
objects                       
unique_error_message          
_set_pk_val                   
_deferred                     
save_base                     
pk                            
serializable_value            
full_clean                    
__init__                      
code                          
save                          
__str__                       
validate_unique               
clean_fields                  
__repr__                      
_perform_unique_checks        
__reduce__                    
_get_unique_checks            
prepare_database_save         
_get_pk_val                   
__eq__                        
lookups                       
_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD
Meta                          
_get_FIELD_display
```

As far as I'm concerned, `PyCharm` is Closed Source, so I think you'll have to talk to the PyCharm developers.

Comment: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6664, Fixed in build -> 120.113